# Traducción consulta SQL a JPQL

Tags: java, sql, java-ee, jpql

Hola amigos estoy intentando traducir esta consulta de SQL a JPQL

```
Select * from participante  where not exists (select 1 from matricula where matricula.id_persona = participante.id_persona and matricula.id_actividad=5);
```

Esto es lo que llevo hecho

```
@Override
public List<Participante> participantesSinMatriculaEnActividad(int codigoActividad) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Participante e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Matricula m WHERE m.idPersona=e.idPersona AND m.idActividad=?1)");
    return query.setParameter(1, codigoActividad).getResultList();

}
```

Pero el IDE me lanza una advertencia en la Query diciendo que las expresiones de la izquierda o de la derecha deben ser de algún tipo.

¿Alguien me podría decir en que estoy fallando ?

Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos

Entidad Participante

```
public class Participante implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/* @Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_persona")
private Integer idPersona;*/
@Id
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", nullable = false)
private Persona idPersona;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", referencedColumnName = "id_persona", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Persona persona;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_carrera", referencedColumnName = "id_carrera")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Carrera carrera;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idPersona")
private Collection<Matricula> matriculaCollection;

public Participante() {
}

public Persona getIdPersona() {
    return idPersona;
}

/*
public Participante(Integer idPersona) {
this.idPersona = idPersona;
}
public Integer getIdPersona() {
return idPersona;
}
public void setIdPersona(Integer idPersona) {
this.idPersona = idPersona;
}
 */
public void setIdPersona(Persona idPersona) {
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
}

public Persona getPersona() {
    return persona;
}

public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
    this.persona = persona;
}

public Carrera getCarrera() {
    return carrera;
}

public void setCarrera(Carrera carrera) {
    this.carrera = carrera;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Matricula> getMatriculaCollection() {
    return matriculaCollection;
}

public void setMatriculaCollection(Collection<Matricula> matriculaCollection) {
    this.matriculaCollection = matriculaCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idPersona != null ? idPersona.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Participante)) {
        return false;
    }
    Participante other = (Participante) object;
    if ((this.idPersona == null && other.idPersona != null) || (this.idPersona != null && !this.idPersona.equals(other.idPersona))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.fcastillo.sistemaextension.Participante[ idPersona=" + idPersona + " ]";
}
```

}

Entidad Matricula

```
public class Matricula implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_matricula")
private Integer idMatricula;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "arancel")
private BigDecimal arancel;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_actividad", referencedColumnName = "id_actividad")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Actividad idActividad;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", referencedColumnName = "id_persona")
//@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Participante idPersona;

public Matricula() {
}

public Matricula(Participante p) {
    //this.idMatricula = idMatricula;
   // this.idActividad = a;
    this.idPersona = p;
}

public Matricula(Integer idMatricula) {
    this.idMatricula = idMatricula;
}

public Integer getIdMatricula() {
    return idMatricula;
}

public void setIdMatricula(Integer idMatricula) {
    this.idMatricula = idMatricula;
}

public BigDecimal getArancel() {
    return arancel;
}

public void setArancel(BigDecimal arancel) {
    this.arancel = arancel;
}

public Actividad getIdActividad() {
    return idActividad;
}

public void setIdActividad(Actividad idActividad) {
    this.idActividad = idActividad;
}

public Participante getIdPersona() {
    return idPersona;
}

public void setIdPersona(Participante idPersona) {
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idMatricula != null ? idMatricula.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Matricula)) {
        return false;
    }
    Matricula other = (Matricula) object;
    if ((this.idMatricula == null && other.idMatricula != null) || (this.idMatricula != null && !this.idMatricula.equals(other.idMatricula))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.fcastillo.sistemaextension.Matricula[ idMatricula=" + idMatricula + " ]";
}
```

}

Advertencia Arrojada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error que aparece al intentar correr la aplicación (Sintaxis sql) 
[image: Error]

ENCONTRÉ LA SOLUCIÓN , la dejo a continuación tal vez le sirva a alguien más.
Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Saludos Cordiales.

```
 @Override
public List<Participante> participantesSinMatriculaEnActividad() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT pj FROM Participante pj WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Matricula v WHERE v.idActividad.idActividad = ?1 AND v.idPersona.idPersona.idPersona = pj.idPersona.idPersona)");
    query.setParameter(1, 5);
    return (List<Participante>) query.getResultList();

}
```

Comment: Puedes añadir las clases de las entidades Participante y Matricula?

Comment: @PabloLozano , ahí las agegué

Comment: Exactamente ¿qué mensaje te lanza? Las IDEs que conozco no suelen evaluar el JPQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que en tu subconsulta

```
SELECT 1 FROM Matricula m WHERE m.idPersona=e.idPersona AND m.idActividad=?1
```

estás comparando objectos directamente, que además son de tipo diferente:

`Matrícula.idPersona` es de tipo `Participante`

`Participante.idPersona` es de tipo `Persona`

Por eso el error te dice, literalmente:

> Las expresiones de la derecha y la izquierda [de la igualdad] deben ser del mismo tipo

Incluso si ambas clases fuesen una hija de la otra, la comparación tendrías que hacerla así (asumiendo que los objectos tienen un id numérico):

```
m.idPersona.id=e.idPersona.id
```